# Jupyterhub - Can't connect to kernel

Tags: kernel, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I can't connect to JupyterHub Kernel (Ipykernel) when I try to execute my own Jupyter Notebook. Here are the logs of Jupyterhub-

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-03-16 10:55:32 UTC, end at Tue 2023-05-16 09:02:40 UTC. --
May 16 09:01:52 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:01:52.384 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/events/subscribe?token=[secret] (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 1.41ms
May 16 09:01:52 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:01:52.605 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/contents/grassland/change/GRAC_1518_020m_at_03035_v010/Symbology?content=1&1684227856997 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 6.76ms
May 16 09:01:59 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:01:59.148 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels?1684227863541 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.14ms
May 16 09:01:59 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:01:59.261 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/terminals?1684227863644 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.03ms
May 16 09:02:01 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:01.808 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/sessions?1684227866203 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 1.76ms
May 16 09:02:01 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:01.812 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517:1219505a-0e07-4b46-b4b0-59d5b1ced34f
May 16 09:02:01 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:01.813 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517/channels?session_id=1219505a-0e07-4b46-b4b0-59d5b1ced34f (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.89ms
May 16 09:02:01 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:01.894 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517?1684227866291 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 1.39ms
May 16 09:02:02 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:02.048 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0:de8fdb6d-43a8-41d7-a09a-740623192779
May 16 09:02:02 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:02.050 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0/channels?session_id=de8fdb6d-43a8-41d7-a09a-740623192779 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 4.84ms
May 16 09:02:02 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:02.142 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0?1684227866534 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.49ms
May 16 09:02:02 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:02.729 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/contents/grassland/change/GRAC_1518_020m_at_03035_v010/Symbology?content=1&1684227867125 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 5.75ms
May 16 09:02:09 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:09.260 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels?1684227873655 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 1.72ms
May 16 09:02:09 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:09.385 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/terminals?1684227873781 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.08ms
May 16 09:02:11 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:11.897 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/sessions?1684227876294 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 1.73ms
May 16 09:02:12 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:12.693 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/events/subscribe?token=[secret] (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.60ms
May 16 09:02:12 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:12.884 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/contents/grassland/change/GRAC_1518_020m_at_03035_v010/Symbology?content=1&1684227877263 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 10.45ms
May 16 09:02:19 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:19.528 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels?1684227883714 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.84ms
May 16 09:02:19 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:19.570 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/terminals?1684227883918 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.30ms
May 16 09:02:21 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:21.981 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/sessions?1684227886375 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.94ms
May 16 09:02:22 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:22.319 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0:de8fdb6d-43a8-41d7-a09a-740623192779
May 16 09:02:22 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:22.321 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0/channels?session_id=de8fdb6d-43a8-41d7-a09a-740623192779 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 5.64ms
May 16 09:02:22 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:22.368 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/7127b6db-c10a-4e97-af01-a153fca0bfd0?1684227886762 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.57ms
May 16 09:02:23 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:23.014 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/contents/grassland/change/GRAC_1518_020m_at_03035_v010/Symbology?content=1&1684227887400 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 11.33ms
May 16 09:02:23 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:23.647 ServerApp] Replacing stale connection: 2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517:1219505a-0e07-4b46-b4b0-59d5b1ced34f
May 16 09:02:23 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [W 2023-05-16 09:02:23.649 ServerApp] 400 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517/channels?session_id=1219505a-0e07-4b46-b4b0-59d5b1ced34f (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 5.10ms
May 16 09:02:23 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:23.754 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels/2a6c7393-2e4e-4ddc-8d36-3a2dc7aa6517?1684227888148 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.85ms
May 16 09:02:29 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:29.579 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels?1684227893969 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 4.52ms
May 16 09:02:29 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:29.660 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/terminals?1684227894056 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.05ms
May 16 09:02:32 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:32.118 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/sessions?1684227896513 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.36ms
May 16 09:02:33 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:33.175 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/contents/grassland/change/GRAC_1518_020m_at_03035_v010/Symbology?content=1&1684227897459 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 11.48ms
May 16 09:02:39 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:39.828 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernels?1684227904021 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.62ms
May 16 09:02:39 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:39.934 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/terminals?1684227904098 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.30ms
May 16 09:02:40 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:40.023 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/kernelspecs?1684227904414 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 4.66ms
May 16 09:02:40 fairicube jupyterhub[2387689]: [I 2023-05-16 09:02:40.027 ServerApp] 200 GET /jhub/user/mbasak/api/me?1684227904415 (mbasak@127.0.0.1) 2.36ms
```

How can I connect to the kernel ?

I set up a Jupyterhub instance in my VM and logged in with my user account (mbasak). While trying to execute the notebook I noticed that it doesn't connect to the kernel because of some reason.

HEre are the relevant jupyter versions-

```
 jupyter-client==8.2.0 
jupyter-core==5.3.0 
jupyter-events==0.6.3 
jupyter-server==2.5.0 
jupyter-server-fileid==0.9.0 
jupyter-server-terminals==0.4.4 
jupyter-server-ydoc==0.8.0 
jupyter-telemetry==0.1.0 
jupyter-ydoc==0.2.4 
jupyterhub==4.0.0 
jupyterhub-sshauthenticator==0.1 
jupyterlab==3.6.3 
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2 
jupyterlab-server==2.22.1
```